# How to making perspectiveTransform for incomplete rectangle

Tags: opencv, contour

I want to do perspectiveTransform for one incomplete rectangle object as it was overlapped by other objects, I think I need to make rectangle complete, and then do the perspectiveTransform, but I am not sure how to achieve that.

One book on the desk is partially covered by clothes, so I want to perspectiveTransform the part which is not covered.

[please refer this image][1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zURcp.png

Comment: Can you show an example of the contours that you're working with?

Comment: I'd love to upload my picture, but have no idea how to do that, sorry, this is my 1st time to use it.